# In Swift, what does it mean for protocol to inherit from class keyword?

Tags: swift, protocols

In Swift, what does it mean for protocol to inherit from class keyword?

e.g.

```
protocol MyDelegate: class {

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The gist of [*Starscream*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118452/2792531) is correct, but it misses the *why* which I think is important here.  It comes down to ARC and memory management.

Swift is a language of reference types and value types.  *Classes* are reference types, while everything else is a value type.  Effectively, we're not really specifying that the protocol *inherits* from `class`... it's more like we're specifying that the protocol can only be implemented by *reference types*.

And why is that important?

It's important, because without it, we can't use the `weak` keyword with the protocol.

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {}

class DelegatedClass {
    weak var delegate: ExampleProtocol?
}
```

This generates the error:

> 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type 'ExampleProtocol'

[image]

And why not?  Because the `weak` keyword only makes sense with reference types to which ARC applies.  ARC does not apply to value types.  And without specifying our protocol with `class`, we cannot guarantee that our `delegate` property is set to a reference-type.  (And if we don't use `weak`, we're most likely creating a retain cycle.)

Answer (score 4):

From the [Apple docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

> You can limit protocol adoption to class types (and not structures or
>   enumerations) by adding the class keyword to a protocol’s inheritance
>   list.

Example:

```
protocol AProtocol: class {   
}

//Following line will produce error: Non-class type 'aStruct' cannot conform to class protocol 'AProtocol'
struct aStruct: AProtocol { 
}
```

The line declaring the structure will spit an error.  Following line will produce error:

> Non-class type '`aStruct`' cannot conform to class protocol '`AProtocol`'