# protocol with "class" after the colon?

Tags: swift

Can anyone explain the following protocol syntax:

```
protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate: class {
  func addItemViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: AddItemViewController)
  func addItemViewController(_ controller: AddItemViewController,
                     didFinishAdding item: ChecklistItem)
}
```

What does "class" do?

Answer (score 3):

It means that the protocol can be adopted only by classes. So no Structure or Enum can adopt this protocol.

> #### Class-Only Protocols
>
> You can limit protocol adoption to class types (and not structures or
> enumerations) by adding the AnyObject protocol to a protocol’s
> inheritance list.
>
> ```
> protocol SomeClassOnlyProtocol: AnyObject, SomeInheritedProtocol {
>     // class-only protocol definition goes here
> }
> ```
>
> In the example above, SomeClassOnlyProtocol can only be adopted by class types. It’s
> a compile-time error to write a structure or enumeration definition
> that tries to adopt SomeClassOnlyProtocol.
>
> **NOTE**
>
> Use a class-only protocol when the behavior defined by that protocol’s
> requirements assumes or requires that a conforming type has reference
> semantics rather than value semantics. For more on reference and value
> semantics, see Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types and Classes
> Are Reference Types.

Reference: [Swift Programming Language - Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281)

Comment: Thanks. There doesn't appear to be anything about using "class" for that purpose in Apple's Swift language [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267).  In the [protocol section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267), the guide mentions using AnyObject for that purpose.

Comment: @7stud: You are correct, I think in the previous versions of that document they were using `class` keyword. The purpose is same, but don't know why the change in keywords. Will do a research on that :)

Comment: Your quote from the reference does not mention `: class`. It seems that Apple changed the documentation (compare this older answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118452/1187415 from the linked-to duplicate targets). – See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176814/whats-the-difference-between-a-protocol-extended-from-anyobject-and-a-class-onl about why it is (apparently) the same.

Comment: @MartinR: I've read the previous docs of Apple Swift, in that they have used class instead of AnyObject (I clearly remember that). Thanks for the second link, I got a clear idea about it now.